# Jquery find remove element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/getLinks.php?url=" + thisArticleUrl

    }).success(function (data) {

        var content = $(data).find("#content > div > div.entry.clearfix");

        content.find("#content > div > div.entry.clearfix > img").remove();

        console.log(content.html())



    });
```

Dont remove content in image. Help me please.

Comment: Don't edit your question to post an answer. Just answer your own question. It's allowed

Comment: @Machavity or OP would you mind removing the non-English bits?

Answer (score 3):

`content` variable already have `#content > div > div.entry.clearfix` inside, you just need to

```
content.find("img").remove();
```

Or

```
$(data).find("#content > div > div.entry.clearfix > img").remove();
```